# What functionality is lost when using django with mongodb?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I am evaluating whether I want to use mongoDB with django for my next project. What I am not sure about, though, is what functionality (ORM, admin, forms, etc.) I loose when I use a DB backend that is not officially supported.

I consider using the [mongodb-engine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html).

Comment: Can the close voters explain me how to rewrite the question?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have [Django-mongoadmin](https://github.com/jschrewe/django-mongoadmin) and [Django-mongonaut](https://github.com/pydanny/django-mongonaut) for django-admin stuff. Also
[Django-mongodbforms](https://github.com/jschrewe/django-mongodbforms) for model forms. [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html) as ORM. But this modules are pretty raw and unstable so use it with wariness.